# SPARQL DELETE WHERE unintentionally deleting all triples from rdfstore database

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfstore

I'm able to retrieve a subset of my graph from [`rdfstore.js`](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js) via the following query:

```
SELECT * { 
    ?subject app:rhymesWith ?object .
    FILTER (?subject = "word" || ?object = "word")
}
```

However, when I try to delete what I  would think is the same subset of triples:

```
DELETE WHERE {
     ?subject app:rhymesWith ?object .
     FILTER(?subject = "word" || ?object = "word")
}
```

It ends up deleting *all* triples, even the ones that don't have the literal on either side.

Why is this happening? I want to delete the same triples returned by the select.

Comment: the query is correct especially when it works for SELECT, thus, it looks like a bug. Or we're both misunderstanding the API and don't know how to do SPARQL update queries. Did you try a simpler query with `DELETE` ? In any case,  you should add the corresponding JS code here so others can see what you're doing.

Comment: That said, you could try 1) the non shortcut query `DELETE ... WHERE ...` or 2) a different JS API first or 3) open a Github ticket  (the last commit was 2 years ago, not sure whether it's still maintained) or 4) you try to debug the code

Comment: I find multiple storage engines named "rdfstore." The SO tag doesn't link to anything, including any of these. Which one are you actually working with?

Comment: @TallTed  Working with https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js

@ AKSW you're right, it's old and seems that it's not maintained but I'm hoping this isnt a bug since it's such a basic feature.

Comment: As AKSW says, your query looks fine, and this definitely looks like a bug, so I'd log an issue ... joining [the many others there](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js/issues).

Comment: Right, the projects seems to be not maintained anymore. All issues after 2016 got no response nor wasn't there any commit since 2016. Why did you chose this old lib instead of e.g. [`rdflib.js`](https://github.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js) which is still maintained and updated frequently? And did you try the more verbose `DELETE ... WHERE ...` ?

Comment: yes I've tried the more verbose version with the same result.  I didn't see rdflib.js before, I'll give it a try thanks.